# JFrame is not acting as expected!

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is my first time using a JFrame. I can't get the window to display the text areas I've nested inside the JFrame. I am trying to get the text field with my name in it to display above the tabulated results, which I have omitted the formatting for until I can get the JFrame to work.

```
public void printResults(String[] names, int[] temp, int[][] scores, float[] averages, char[] letters){

    JTextArea outarea= new JTextArea(5,20);
    JTextArea name = new JTextArea(5,20);
    Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 48);
    name.setFont(font);
    name.setText("Made By Durka Durka");

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.getContentPane().add(name);
    window.getContentPane().add(outarea);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.pack();
    window.getContentPane().setVisible(true)

    String out = "foo";

    outarea.setText(out);


    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,window);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probable reason why the `JFrame` is not appearing is because of this line:

```
window.getContentPane().setVisible(true)
```

The above line is setting the visibility of the `Container` to which the `JTextArea`s have been added, but does not control the visibility of the `JFrame` itself -- therefore, the `JFrame` itself is not being displayed.

(To be more precise, the [`JFrame.getContentPane`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane()) method returns a `Container`, so the above code is actually calling the `Containter`'s `setVisible` method.)

Try the following instead:

```
window.setVisible(true);
```

This will set the visibility of the `JFrame` itself to be visible.

Also, as the other answers have suggested, try using [Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to control the locations of where the components should be displayed. The following are links to using two of the several Layout Managers which could be used to layout components.

- [How to Use BorderLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
- [How to Use GridLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: This fixed it. I did not realize that you could have visible invisible sections.

Answer (score 2):

You should use some of the layout managers. This link should help you:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

The standard java layout managers are sometimes really hard to handle. Maybe you should also look into the JGoodies: http://www.jgoodies.com/ "Framework". It is easier to use and you realize that even a java gui can look nice..

Answer (score 1):

First things first - are you calling printResults on the Event Dispatch Thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable runnable);` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable runnable);`?  Remember that you need to do all GUI work on the EDT.

If so, try this:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
// CHANGES HERE
window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout();
window.getContentPane().add(name, BorderLayout.NORTH);
window.getContentPane().add(outarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
// END CHANGES
```